# Root attacks on the Android credential storage

Tags: android, root, keychain

I'm wondering about the impact on the Android KeyChain if an attacker manages to root the device. Can anyone shed some light on this? Could you also make the distinction between hardware-backed (f.i. devices like the Nexus 4) and non-hardware backed credential storage?

How much of a role does the passcode strength play in such cases?

In addition, I would be most grateful for sources where I can verify this information.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

https://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/index.html

I believe this guys have a better and more concrete response to your question.

But hey, if you want my 10 cents... Android is "secure enough". A rooted device only means a user can retrieve otherwise blocked content and files from its device and run processes with full control, but it does not means it can simply see KeyChain in clear text pair values.

Even if you do have the skills to retrieve the key and break its codification (that actually could take weeks, or months, or more time then one would spend), it is way to much trouble to root a bazzillion devices out there.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, reis_eliel. In this link https://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/enhancements43.html the authors mention that the hardware-bound keys cannot be exported off the device, even in the case of a root compromise. I understand that. But what my question boils down to, is: are the hardware-backed private keys available to an attacker to carry out decryptions or does he need the user's passcode to "activate" them somehow? The answer to my question would cover the case where an attacker (1) has physical access to the device (2) has managed to root the device.

Answer (score -1):

If your phone is rooted, then the hacker will manage to USE the keys in the hardware store

He will not manage to COPY them.

Since USING the keys is really what a hacker wants to do, it does mean that your security is absolutely compromised if the device is rooted.

Comment: There are several aspects to the question. Are you able to expand your answer to cover them?